# separate first word in a string in python re

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to separate strings into two groups; the first word and the second word or group of words. The words are separated by an underscore and when I use my current code, if there are more than one underscores, it only separates off the last. Here is the code I currently have:

```
for record in reader:
s = record['trial']
patternsubgen = re.compile(r'(\w+)\(\w+\)\_(\w+)')
source = "Footit"
if patternsubgen.search(s):
    resultsubgen = patternsubgen.search(s)
    genussubgen = resultsubgen.group(1)
    speciessubgen = resultsubgen.group(2)
    subgen = '%s %s' % (genussubgen, speciessubgen)
    #print(subgen)
else:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\_(\w+)')
    if pattern.search(s):
        result = pattern.search(s)
        genus = result.group(1)
        species = result.group(2)
        new = '%s %s' % (genus, species)
        print(new)
```

Here are some examples of the strings:

```
Aphis(Aphis)_asclepiadis, Cinara_011, Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a,
```

what I need is:

```
Aphis asclepiadis,
Cinara 011,
Clydesmithia canadensis_1a,
```

what I am getting is:

```
Aphis asclepiadis,
Cinara 011,
Clydesmithia_canadensis 1a
```

Comment: Can these strings be found in the wild?

Comment: What about `Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a_2b`?

Comment: Something like [**`\b([^_\W]+)(?:\([^()]+\))?_(\w+)\b`**](https://regex101.com/r/P69Uw8/1/) ?

Answer (score 1):

### Code

#### Option 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/18IKc9/5)

```
(\w+?(?=[(_])).*?_(\w+)
```

Replacement

```
$1 $2
```

#### Option 2

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/18IKc9/6)

```
([^_\W]+).*?[)_](\w+)
```

Replacement

```
$1 $2
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Aphis(Aphis)_asclepiadis, Cinara_011, Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a,
Aphis(Aphis)test_asclepiadis, Cinara_011, Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a_test,
```

#### Output

**Option 1**

```
Aphis asclepiadis, Cinara 011, Clydesmithia canadensis_1a,
Aphis asclepiadis, Cinara 011, Clydesmithia canadensis_1a_test,
```

**Option 2**

```
Aphis _asclepiadis, Cinara 011, Clydesmithia canadensis_1a,
Aphis test_asclepiadis, Cinara 011, Clydesmithia canadensis_1a_test,
```

---

### Explanation

#### Option 1

- `(\w+?(?=[(_]))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\w+?` Match one or more word characters, but as few as possible
  - `(?=[(_])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches a character in the set `(_`
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `_` Match the underscore character `_` literally
- `(\w+)` Capture any word character one or more times into capture group 2

#### Option 2

- `([^_\W]+)` Capture one or more word characters except `_` into capture group 1
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `[)_]` Match either `)` or `_` literally
- `(\w+)` Capture one or more word characters into capture group 2

Answer (score 1):

For the given strings, you could use

```
\b([^_\W]+)(?:\([^()]+\))?_(\w+)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/P69Uw8/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

strings = 'Aphis(Aphis)_asclepiadis, Cinara_011, Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a,'

rx = re.compile(r'\b([^_\W]+)(?:\([^()]+\))?_(\w+)\b')

strings = rx.sub("\g<1> \g<2>", strings)
print(strings)
# Aphis asclepiadis, Cinara 011, Clydesmithia canadensis_1a,
```

Comment: How about `Aphis(Aphis)test_asclepiadis, Cinara_011, Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a_test,`?

Comment: @revo: Not sure what OP wants, really.

Answer (score 0):

There are already good regex answers. You can achieve your goal with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) alone, though. It accepts an argument specifying the maximum number of splits:

```
records = ["Aphis(Aphis)_asclepiadis", "Cinara_011", "Clydesmithia_canadensis_1a"]

for record in records:
    left, right = record.split('_', 1) # Split no more than once.
    left = left.split('(')[0]          # Remove anything after '('
    print(' '.join([left, right]))
# Aphis asclepiadis
# Cinara 011
# Clydesmithia canadensis_1a
```

By the way, you shouldn't call `re.compile` inside the loop. It's an expensive operation and the pattern doesn't change between records.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your answer. I have two questions: 1. how can I rewrite the code so I'm avoiding compiling twice; there are other actions I need to perform on the record, but I don't know how to do them without compiling. 2.  I tried using the code you provided, but my terminal says ''dict' object has no attribute 'split'. I'm in csv.DictReader- could that be causing this, or is there another problem? Using split may fix some of the other problems I'm having, so it might be really useful.

Comment: @birdoptera: Simply move the `re.compile` lines before the for loop. `split` should be called on a string, not a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements are not clear enough, hence some ambiguous use cases. But looking at your own code and subject string together, I'd offer such Regular Expression:

```
\(\w+\)_(\w+)|_(\w+)
```

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/meiDhG/1)

[Python live demo](https://ideone.com/OkGq4i)